# Ionic4 - How to make a fixed background with other layers at the front app

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic4

I'm trying to create an app which uses Google Maps for setting a dynamic map in the background while setting other layers at the front. The map will stay in the background all the time and other layers will come up depending on user interaction.

How do I achieve these on Ionic4/Angular?

Comment: `z-index` should be able to do this... set googlemap div as height/width 100%

Comment: How should the code/pages/components be structured?

Comment: googlemaps could be an item in the HTML or a different component; first: load your map as an item on the page; Second: use CSS to put the googlemaps as a background and everything else on top; give it a quick try on stackblitz and you can ask for help when stuck